# Proving that we can divide a graph to two graphs which induced subgraph is connected on vertices of each one

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Assume that we have a graph, say $G$, with $100$ vertices, and our graph has no articulation points (a vertex that the graph will become unconnected if we remove it from the graph). Prove that we can divide vertices of $G$ into two groups ($50$ vertices each), such that the [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) is connected in each group.

Comment: Can't you just pick any single vertex as one set and all the rest of the vertices as the other set?

Comment: @AdamLowrance Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that each group should have 50 vertices. Edited, thank you.